# Set localhost port fixed/static for project debugging in vs2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015

l am  using Asp.Net Maker 2016 for generating my project. So, l browse my project via vs2015. The problem is after I generate my project from Asp.Net Maker tool and open it in vs2015, the URL of my project is changed.

something like :

```
http://localhost:51624/ADD
```

I want to set the port fixed not dynamic so, how I can do this in vs2015 or  Asp.Net 2016 Maker tool?

Answer (score 1):

**Visual Studio** uses **IIS Express** to run **Web Projects**. When a project is run first time **IISExpress** creates an entry to `applicationhost.config` file for the project and assigns a random port to it. The file is located at - `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config` folder.

Project entries in the file looks like this -

```
<site name="ProjectName" id="5">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="d:\physical path" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:59302:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Notice the `bindingInformation="*:59302:localhost"` in the above section. Here the port number is `59302`. You can change this port number to anything you like and next time **Visual Studio** runs the project it will use your assigned port number.

Its best to close all instances of VS and also confirm that **IISExpress** is not running before changing the file. Also, keep a backup of the file beforehand just in case.

The port you assign also needs to be free. i.e. no other application should be using the port. Else **Visual Studio** will fail to run the application.